# Save Many-to-many relation with extra columns Jpa

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, lombok, postgresql-9.6

I'm in this situation. I have three entities: Form, FormComponent and FormComponentJoin.
It is a many-to-many relation with extra column.
I would like to save a form entity and all his children with a single call to the FormRepository save() method but it doesn't work.
This is the error message:
The error is Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing
These are my entities:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "form")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Form implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "form", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, orphanRemoval = true)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @Singular
    private List<FormComponentJoin> formComponentJoin = new ArrayList<>();

}

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Entity
@Table(name = "form_component")
@AllArgsConstructor(suppressConstructorProperties = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
public class FormComponent implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "formComponent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private List<FormComponentJoin> formComponentJoin = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    private FormComponent parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Singular
    private List<FormComponent> children;

    private String value;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "form_component_join")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class FormComponentJoin implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "form_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Form form;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "form_component_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private FormComponent formComponent;

    @Column(name = "position")
    private int pos;

}

@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface FormRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Form, String> {

}
```

In order to do tests I use the CommandLineRunner:

```
@Bean
public CommandLineRunner initDatabase(FormRepository formRepository) {
    return (args) -> {

    FormComponent formComponent1 = FormComponent.builder().value("test").build();
    formComponent1.setChildren(null);
    formComponent1.setParent(null);

    FormComponentJoin formComponentJoin1 = FormComponentJoin.builder().pos(1).formComponent(formComponent1).build();

    Form form = Form.builder().name("test").build()).child(formComponentJoin1).build();
    formComponentJoin1.setForm(form);       

    form = formRepository.save(form);   

}
```

This is the full stack trace:

Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : org.fao.backend.entity.FormComponentJoin.formComponent -> org.fao.backend.entity.FormComponent
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$8.noCascade(CascadingActions.java:398)
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:129)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:442)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.justCascade(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:188)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsPersistent(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:181)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:145)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:838)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:831)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$8.cascade(CascadingActions.java:357)
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:350)
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:293)
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:379)
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:319)
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:296)
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:118)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.cascadeOnFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:167)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:158)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:91)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:55)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1258)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77)
        ... 58 common frames omitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I understand that the error was the mapping in the FormComponentJoin entity.

This is the new mapping:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE })
@JoinColumn(name = "form_id") // , referencedColumnName = "id"
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
@JsonIgnore
private Form form;

@ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
@JoinColumn(name = "form_component_id") // , referencedColumnName = "id"
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
private FormComponent formComponent;
```